# Setting up the AWS Tools for PowerShell Core on Linux

Tags: package-management, permissions, sudo, dotnet, powershell

The AWS [utility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-linux-mac.html) has this to say about privileges:

> Note
>
> Although you can start PowerShell by running sudo pwsh to run
>   PowerShell with elevated rights, be aware that this is a potential
>   security risk, and not consistent with the principle of least
>   privilege.

Fair enough, but then how is the module installed?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore                                                             
Install-Module : Administrator rights are required to install modules in '/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules'. Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install '/home/thufir/.local/share/powershell/Modules' by adding "-Scope CurrentUser" to your command. You can also try running the Windows PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Module], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InstallModuleNeedsCurrentUserScopeParameterForNonAdminUser,Install-Module

PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> exit                                                                                                   
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo pwsh
[sudo] password for thufir: 
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore                                                             

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its 
InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 
'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): n
WARNING: User declined to install module (AWSPowerShell.NetCore).
PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> exit                                                                                                   
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe they accidentally swapped the commands here:

> Next, run Install-Module as shown in the following command.
>
> ```
> PS> Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -AllowClobber
> ```
>
> It is not necessary to run this command as Administrator, unless you
>   want to install the AWS Tools for PowerShell Core for all users of a
>   computer. To do this, run the following command in a PowerShell
>   session that you have started with sudo pwsh:
>
> ```
> PS> Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser -Name AWSPowerShell.NetCore -Force
> ```

`-Scope CurrentUser` installs this for your user only, and doesn't need administrator privileges. Without that, it installs the module for all users, and does need privileges. See [the `Install-Modules` documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-6):

> When no scope is defined, or when the value of the `Scope` parameter
>   is `AllUsers`, the module is installed to `%systemdrive%:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. When the value of `Scope` is
>   `CurrentUser`, the module is installed to
>   `$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

To install without `sudo`, use `-Scope CurrentUser`. This is like `--user` for `pip install`, for example.